# encoding Lithuanian character in xml using python

Tags: python, xml, encoding, decoding

I have a code:

```
def convert_df_to_xml(df,fd,ld):
# sukuriam pagrindini elementa (root) su pavadinimu Invoices.
root = ET.Element("Invoices")
root.set("from", str(fd))
root.set("till", str(ld))
for i in range(len(df['partner_id'])):
    # pridedam sub elementa.
    invoices = ET.SubElement(root, "Invoice")
    invoices.set('clientid',df['company_registry'][i])
    invoices.set('imones_pavadinimas', df['partner_id'][i])

    # pridedam sub-sub elementa.
    quebec = ET.SubElement(invoices, "Product")

    # susikraunam eiluciu info is dataframe
    sectin_1 = ET.SubElement(quebec, "Name")
    sectin_1.text = str(df["Name"][i])
    sectin_2 = ET.SubElement(quebec, 'Quantity')
    sectin_2.text = str(df["time_dif"][i])
    sectin_3 = ET.SubElement(quebec, 'Price')
    sectin_3.text = str(df["price_unit"][i])


xmlstr = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root)).toprettyxml(indent="  ", encoding="UTF-8").decode("UTF-8")
with open("bandomasis_itp_xml_failas_V_1.1.xml", "w") as f:
    f.write(xmlstr)
```

I'm creating xml file from python DataFrame. The problem is that in xml file I got "?" marks instead "ė" character.

In dataframe i have strings with characters "ė,ą,š,ų" and I need them to be in xml file.
My dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'partner_id': ['MED GRUPĖ, UAB'], 'Name':['Pirmas'], 'company_registry': ['3432543'],
                'time_dif':['2'],'price_unit':['23']})
```

what is the problem with encoding here?

Comment: I have eddited code and entered a dataframe (df1)

Comment: You don't have to encode anything. Python 3 strings are Unicode already. The file's text encoding is a parameter of `open`. `encoding="UTF-8").decode("UTF-8")` will return the original string at best, or mangle it. Use `with open("bandomasis_itp_xml_failas_V_1.1.xml", "w",encoding="utf-8") `

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]…

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis Kanavos it helped me a lot! :)